# RecyclerView item animation: Only animate initially visible items

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have the following code to animate RecyclerView items. This works very good but it animates all items that are appearing if I scroll down.

What I want is an behaviour like in Google Play Music app where the animation is only played for the items that are **initially visible**. The items that are getting visible through scrolling should appear as there is no Animation Adapter. Any idea how to archive this behaviour?

```
  public class RecyclerViewAnimationAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private int m_LastPosition = -1;

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);

            animateItem(position, holder.ItemView);
        }

        public override void OnViewDetachedFromWindow(Object holder)
        {
            base.OnViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

            var viewToAnimate = ((RecyclerView.ViewHolder) holder).ItemView;

            viewToAnimate.ClearAnimation();
        }

        private void animateItem(int position, View viewToAnimate)
        {
            if (position > m_LastPosition)
            {
                var animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.slide_in_bottom);

                viewToAnimate.StartAnimation(animation);

                m_LastPosition = position;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this method in Android Studio and it worked, it should work for you too with some little tweaks:

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private boolean isAnimation;

    YourAdapter(... )
    {
       ...
       this.isAnimation = true;
    }
    ....


    private void switchAnimation(boolean isAnimation)
    {
        this.isAnimation = isAnimation;
    }


    private void animateItem(int position, View viewToAnimate)
    {
        if (position > m_LastPosition && isAnimation)
        {
            var animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Application.Context, Resource.Animation.slide_in_bottom);

            viewToAnimate.StartAnimation(animation);

            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
```

}

Then in your LayoutManager override the method `onLayoutChildren` (You have to accomodate the code to C#) :

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
            myAdapter.switchAnimation(false);
        }
    };
```

Let me know if that helped ;)

Comment: Hi Nabil. Thank you so much. I will try it later this day :)

Comment: I think `m_LastPosition` should be `lastPosition`